# Private Cocapods repo in devops Pipelines

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, cocoapods

Working with Azure Devops and iOS is a first to me.
I am trying to create a Build Pipeline in Azure devops for an iOS App that has several private cocoapods repository (`PodXSource`) and a private spec repository(`projectPodSpecsRepository`).

I can't seem to manage to execute the Azure Cocoapod task. I've tried several ways but none are working. Am I missing something?

here is a part of my yaml pipeline:

```
- script: 
          git clone https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpecsRepository

          git config --global credential.helper store

          git clone https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/Pod1Source

          git clone https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectEvaluations/_git/Pod2Source

          git clone https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectEvaluations/_git/Pod3Source

          git clone https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectEvaluations/_git/Pod4Source

          git clone https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectEvaluations/_git/Pod5Source


- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: false
```

The `$(gitUser)` and `$(gitPat)` are both pipeline secrets for credentials purposes.

The Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

source 'https://dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpecsRepository'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'projectDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for projectDemo
  pod 'Pod1'
  pod 'Pod2'
  pod 'Pod3'
  pod 'Pod4'
  pod 'Pod5'

end
```

Here is the log from the `CocoaPods` task:

```
##[section]Starting: CocoaPods
==============================================================================
Task         : CocoaPods
Description  : Install CocoaPods dependencies for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects
Version      : 0.151.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/cocoapods
==============================================================================
[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod --version
1.7.1
[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod install
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.7.3) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.7.1). Incompatibility issues may arise.
Analyzing dependencies
Adding spec repo `azure-happydump-projectcore-_git-projectpodspecsrepository` with CDN `https://dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpec`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpec` named `azure-happydump-projectcore-_git-projectpodspecsrepository`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/vsts/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
##[error]The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[error]The 'pod' command failed with error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: CocoaPods
```

I followed [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/215131/cocoapod-build-task-support-private-cocoapods.html) link to get there but nothing does the trick.

I can't seem to find a way to make that work. Thanks for your time.

EDIT: using `gem install cocoapods` to the yaml file just deletes the `[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.7.3) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.7.1). Incompatibility issues may arise.` warning but doesn't fix the problem.

EDIT2: Using `pod repo add azure-happydump-projectcore-_git-projectpodspecsrepository https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpecsRepository` doesn't help either. Tha error message from the CocoaPods task will just change to `... [!] Unable to add a source with url https://dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpec named azure-happydump-projectcore-_git-projectpodspecsrepository-1. ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was due to an a url formatting difference within the Podfile.lock file:

Podfile: 
`https://dev.azure.com/happydump/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpecsRepository`

Podfile.lock `https://happydump@visualstudio.com/DefaulCollection/projectCore/_git/projectPodSpecsRepository`

reverting the url from the Podfile.lock did the trick!

Here are the final files:

Pipeline: Note that I am zipping the cocoapods repo in order not to clone them for each build.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables: 
  FILEEXISTS: false

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'sudo gem install cocoapods'


- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CP_HOME_DIR;]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache"'

- task: CacheBeta@0
  inputs:
    key: PodReposTestZip | $(Agent.OS) | $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Konectom/Podfile.lock
    path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache/tmp/
  displayName: Cache Podfiles packages


- bash: |
    if [ -d $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache/tmp ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS]true"
    fi

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache/tmp/cocoapods.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache/repos'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
  condition: eq(variables.FILEEXISTS, 'true')

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'pod repo add azure-company-project-_git-specrepository-ios https://$(gitUser):$(gitPat)@dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo'

- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: false
    workingDirectory: 'AppDir'

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'Certificats.p12'
    certPwd: '$(certifPwd)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'ProvisionFile.mobileprovision'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: 'Konectom-dev'
    sdk: "iphoneos13.0"
    xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
    xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_11.app'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'Konectom/Konectom.xcworkspace'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    provisioningProfileUuid: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
    exportPath: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/pkgApp

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'ls -la $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/pkgApp'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache/repos/cocoapods'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Cache/tmp/cocoapods.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
  condition: eq(variables.FILEEXISTS, 'false')

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenterEndpoint'
    appSlug: 'TestProject/TestApp'
    appFile: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/pkgApp/App.ipa
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: ''
    destinationType: 'groups'
    symbolsOption: Apple
```

PodFile :

```
workspace 'Project'
#
# Sources reposotiries
#
source 'https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/PodSpecsRepository'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Global project platform
platform :ios, '10.0'

# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

#
# Pods groups
#
def module0
  pod 'po1', '~> 0.1.87'
  pod 'pod2', '~> 0.1.29'
  pod 'pod3', '~> 0.1.20'
  pod 'pod4', '~> 0.1.13'
  pod 'pod5', '~> 0.1.15'
  pod 'pod6', '~> 0.1.15'
  pod 'pod7', '~> 0.1.18'
  pod 'pod8', '~> 0.1.10'
end

def Module1
  pod 'pod1', '~> 0.1.20'
end

def module2
  pod 'pod2', '~> 0.1.16'
end

def module3
  pod 'pod3', '~> 0.1.6'
end

def module4
  pod 'pod4', '~> 0.1.0'
end

def module5
  pod 'pod5', '~> 0.1.8'
end

def module6
  pod 'pod6'
end

#
# Main app target
#
target 'MainProject' do
  project 'MainProject'

  # Private Pods for Project
  privateRepo1
  privateRepo2
  privateRepo3
  privateRepo4
  privateRepo5
  privateRepo6

  # Third party pods
  pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'SPPermissions/Camera'
  pod 'SPPermissions/Location'
  pod 'SPPermissions/Notification'
  pod 'SPPermissions/Motion'

  target 'TestsProject' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'UiTestsProject' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Post install routine
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     # force swift version 4.0 for these pods
     if target.name == ‘SlideMenuControllerSwift’
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings[‘SWIFT_VERSION’] = ‘4.0’
       end
     end
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings[‘EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY’] = “”
         config.build_settings[‘CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED’] = “NO”
         config.build_settings[‘CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED’] = “NO”
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - pod1(0.1.29):
    - Kronos (~> 4.0.0)
  - pod2(0.1.20)
  - Alamofire (5.0.0-rc.3)
  - pod3(0.1.32):
    - pod2(~> 0.1.20)
    - pod1(~> 0.1.29)
    - lottie-ios (~> 2.5.0)
  - Kronos (4.0.0)
  - lottie-ios (2.5.3)
  - SlideMenuControllerSwift (4.0.0)
  - SPPermissions/Camera (4.1.4):
    - SPPermissions/Core
  - SPPermissions/Core (4.1.4)
  - SPPermissions/Location (4.1.4):
    - SPPermissions/Core
  - SPPermissions/Motion (4.1.4):
    - SPPermissions/Core
  - SPPermissions/Notification (4.1.4):
    - SPPermissions/Core

DEPENDENCIES:
  - pod1(~> 0.1.20)
  - pod2(~> 0.1.10)
  - pod3(~> 0.1.15)
  - pod4(~> 0.1.29)
  - pod5(~> 0.1.0)
  - SlideMenuControllerSwift (~> 4.0)
  - SPPermissions/Camera
  - SPPermissions/Location
  - SPPermissions/Motion
  - SPPermissions/Notification

SPEC REPOS:
  https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/PodSpecsRepository:
    - pod1
    - pod2
    - pod3
    - pod4
    - pod5
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git:
    - Alamofire
    - AppCenter
    - GzipSwift
    - KDCircularProgress
    - Kronos
    - lottie-ios
    - SlideMenuControllerSwift
    - SPPermissions
    - SwiftKeychainWrapper

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  checksums

PODFILE CHECKSUM: checksum
COCOAPODS: 1.8.4
```

Comment: Please could you provide these steps in your yml files and pod file?

Comment: Yeah, please share the yml files, so we can see all the details.

Comment: I Added the requested files, sorry I had to find the time to do it. @Jules